# document.getElementById suppress when null

Tags: javascript, html, null

I am trying to find a way to suppress when document.getElementById is null without having to change the code (e.g. put an if statement). Is there any way I can do this so the rest of the rest of the javascript calls after the null value are still executed without changing the code for each place this occurs?

I am aware that I can put some checks (e.g. if statements etc.), however I am trying to avoid that.

Example code:

```
  function example(){
         if(document.getElementById('fruits') == 0){ // this will be null
           doSomething() 
      } 
         var y = 1;
         alert(y);

     }
```

In the above, if x is null, the rest of the lines will not execute. I am trying to find
 a way to 'bypass' the null without having to put checks, if/else statements etc. However, I am using legacy code that has many of these issues.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Can you post some code?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want. What do you mean by "suppress"?

Comment: I am dealing with some legacy code written by others. there are some select tags that don't exist anymore. For example in my code I have something like:  document.getElementById('fruits'); var x = 1; alert(x). In this case, there is no select tag with ID 'fruits', hence it will return a null the next two lines will not be executed. I am looking for a way to have the code still execute without having to remove lines such as document.getElementById('fruits') that return null.

Comment: But why wouldn't you remove those lines if they are not relevant anymore? What do you get from dirty patching this?

Comment: I have many of them in the code. What is a bit odd is that it works with IE but not with Chrome. In other words, rather than putting a 'bandaid', I want to get solve it for all.

Comment: @user3175046 - As we expected, you're looking for a shortcut rather than actually fixing the code the right way.  That's a bad idea.  Put the right fix in by removing the code that should no longer be there.

Comment: Okay thank you.. I was just exploring options. I thought of something like this but didn't find anything.

Comment: Your code example is wrong.  If `x` is null, the following lines will still execute just fine because all you've done is store `null` in a variable which is fine.  It's only when you try to do something like `x.addEventListener()` that you will get an exception because `null` doesn't have that method.

Comment: yes you are right. In my actual code there is no assigning, it is more like checking the value if(document.getElemenyBy('fruits') == 1) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't posted any code (you pretty much always get a better answer if you post your code), the only theoretical answer we can offer is "No", you can't do what you're asking.  If you have code like this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("test");
obj.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // event handler code here
})
```

Then, if you want to make this not generate errors when the `test` object doesn't exist, then you MUST put an `if` statement in to check the return value of `getElementById()` in order to avoid the error on the next line.

---

Without more specific context (since you have included NO code), I must say that your question sounds like general programming laziness.  It sounds like you don't want to add proper error handling in code that needs it and you're looking for a lazy way out.

---

Other ideas to consider.

You can use exception handlers around blocks of code to catch exceptions.  Because exception handlers don't perform as well as `if` statments, you generally want to use exception handlers for unexpected error conditions, not regular return paths, but they can certainly be used to catch issues of missing DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use this in production code...

```
var dummyNode = document.createElement('div');
document.getElementByIdOriginal = document.getElementById;
document.getElementById = function(id) {
    var element = document.getElementByIdOriginal(id);
    return (element) ? element : dummyNode;
}
```

Comment: he can return whatever he wants instead of `null`

Comment: And, how will that make the rest of his code that uses that return result in unspecified ways continue to work and not generate errors?

Comment: Agreed, this just seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: @jfriend00 because he can return a different node so that any code acting on it will mess with his specified node instead of throwing an error when it encounters null

Comment: @Austin - if that's what you propose, then your answer should show that because that's not what your code shows at all (you are returning `true` which won't do any of that).  Personally, I think this is a bad idea.  It sounds like the OP wants to just avoid proper error handling and somehow bury errors which is not a good idea.

Comment: @jfriend00 added in edit. I agree this is a terrible idea, but it is a solution to the question asked.

Comment: Everyone picks their own strategy for providing answers here on SO, but I try to understand what the OP is really doing and refrain from giving them answers to the literal question that are actually a bad way of doing things.  Many questions here on SO ask how to accomplish a particular solution (that is already a bad way to go) and the better answers attempt to understand the actual problem and suggest a good solution to that rather than just answer what was asked.

Comment: To each their own. I feel that if we don't offer the literal solution it will be a disservice to future visitors with the same question who might have a legitimate need for the literal answer.